# Passing an interface implementation as a Spring @RequestBody argument

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have the the following classes:

```
public class ItemController implements ApiController<Item> {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Item create(@RequestBody final CreateItemRequest request) {
    // ...
  }
}

public interface ApiController<T> {
  T create(@RequestBody final ApiRequest request);
}


public class CreateItemRequest implements ApiRequest {
  // ...
}

public interface ApiRequest {
  // ...
}
```

I'm warned by Intellij that `ItemController` does not implement `ApiController`. My working assumption is that `CreateItemRequest`, as an implementation of `ApiRequest`, is a valid type for the signature of the `create` method as it's written above. However, Intellij insists that the type of the `request` parameter should be `ApiRequest`.

My goal here is to have a common interface for classes like `CreateItemRequest` to implement. That interface would be referred to in a generic-y sort of way within `ApiController` methods.

Obviously, I'm not a generics wizard, so what have I mixed up here?

edit: `ThingRequest` properly implements `ApiRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

**You can not narrow method parameters while implementing an interface!** - The

You have an `interface ApiController<T>` with the method `T create(final ApiRequest request)`. This interface tells a client that he can invoke the method `create` with ANY!!! class that implements `ApiRequest`, therefore it is not allowed to have a implementation of `ApiController` that restrict the argument type of `create` to `CreateItemRequest`!!

---

old answer:

You wrote:

```
public interface ApiController<T> {
  T create(@RequestBody final ApiRequest request);
}
```

and

```
public class ItemController implements ApiController<Item> {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Thing create(@RequestBody final CreateItemRequest request) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

One problem is the method argument, **the problem is the return type!** `Thing` is not `Item`!

*OK you told that this is an typo, so read the update above*

---

*BTW: I strongly recommend to add the `@Override` annotation to methods that implement/override other methods*

Comment: oy, good catch, but that was just a mistake in my obfuscation. The return type is definitely "Item".